# Android Jetpack Compose. Using Stack layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Does anyone know how to work with the composable Stack layout?
I understand, that it has to work similar to the RelativeLayout we all know. However, I am not getting the result I need. Instead of one view being drawn over the other, the first one completely covers the second (or the second does not get drawn at all).
I am trying to place a Text in the center of the Toolbar and a Button aligning the right side of the screen.

```
TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Stack(modifier = Modifier.None) {
                    Align(alignment = Alignment.Center) {
                        Text(
                            text = "MyApp",
                            style = (+themeTextStyle { h6 }).withOpacity(0.7f)
                        )
                    }
                    Align(alignment = Alignment.CenterRight) {
                        CircleImageButton(
                            resource = Res.drawable.ic_action_reload,
                            onCLick = onRefreshClick
                        )
                    }
                }
            },
            color = Color.White
        )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `1.0.0-alpha03` the [**`Stack`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#stack) is a composable that positions its children relative to its edges.

Just an example with a rectangle of 300x300 in the Center, and 2 rectangles of 150x150 in the `TopStart`/`BottomEnd` angles using the Use [`StackScope.gravity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/StackScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).gravity(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment))

```
Stack {

    Box(
        backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .width(300.dp)
            .height(300.dp))

    Box(
        backgroundColor = Color.Green,
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.TopStart)
            .width(150.dp)
            .height(150.dp))

    Box(
        backgroundColor = Color.Red,
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
            .width(150.dp)
            .height(150.dp))
}
```

[image]

About the [TopAppBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#topappbar) you can use something like:

```
TopAppBar(
    title = {
        Text(text = "TopAppBar")
    },
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { }) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu)
        }
    },
    actions = {
        // RowScope here, so these icons will be placed horizontally
        IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite)
        }
        IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite)
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: FYI, [plagiarizing in tag wikis](https://web.archive.org/web/20200506021436if_/https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/layout/package-summary.html) (regarding [andriod-compose-stack](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/fix-a-typo-in-andriod-compose-stack-tag-name)) [has consequences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313486/6296561). Don't do that again

Comment: @Zoe Thanks for your message.Sorry for that, my bad. I am going to check all policies about tag wikis.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the replacement for `Stack` is just `Box`?